# HTML and CSS irregular triangle image gallery

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I need to create an image gallery, in which the individual images are irregular triangles (emphasis on irregular).

I found limited examples on how to achieve triangle images via html and css, without modifying the images themselves. One example I found in this CodePen https://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/liDCz was a step in the right direction, but looking at it, I can't find a way to make the images irregular triangles.

The result I am trying to achieve is this:
[image: Image section]

```
  <div class='pageOption'>
      <a href='#' class='option'>
          <img src='~/images/team/pic_paggas/A.png'>
      </a>
      <a href='#' class='option'>
          <img src='~/images/team/pic_paggas/D.png'>
      </a>
   </div>
```

This is the basic HTML I will be using and the CSS is:

```
.pageOption {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 40em;
    height: 27em;
}

.option, .option img {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}

.option {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    transform: skewX(-55.98deg);
}

.option:first-child {
    left: -.25em;
    transform-origin: 100% 0;
}

.option:last-child {
    right: -.25em;
    transform-origin: 0 100%;
}

.option img {
    opacity: .75;
    transition: .5s;
}

    .option img:hover {
        opacity: 1;
    }

.option img, .option:after {
    transform: skewX(55.98deg);
    transform-origin: inherit;
}
```

Mind that the HTML and CSS I have may not be the optimal for my problem. I think the shape of the images I am using (rectangular) have something to do with this.

Would be better if the solution is better supported across browsers.

Comment: clip-path maybe : https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I should have mentioned that I looked at that also, but I would prefer a solution that is better supported than clip-path. As I understood I would have to create polyfills for older browsers if I use clip-path.

Comment: Well, I think that suggestion was great for what your use-case looks like (some sort of showcase), but you might as well put an SVG mask the same color as the background in front your image, that should be widely supported...

Comment: I'll search around a bit longer, but it seems I'll be reverting to clip-path

Comment: Why not use SVG for that? Clip path is great, but it is still poorly supported. SVG solution would work on everything >= IE 9.

Comment: Scrapped the idea. Initially I used SVG pattern fill that worked in Chrome, but after seeing how it looks like in IE11 I decided I won't invest more time in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with skew like below if you cannot use clip-path:

```css
.box {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display:inline-block;
}

.triangle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: skewX(-20deg) skewY(45deg); /* 27deg instead of 20deg to have a regular triangle */
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-size:0 0;
}
.triangle.bottom {
  transform-origin: top right;
}

.triangle:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  background-image: inherit;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
  transform: skewY(-45deg) skewX(20deg); /* We invert order AND signs*/
  transform-origin: inherit;
}

.triangle:hover {
 filter:grayscale(100%);
}

.adjust {
  margin-left:-120px;
}

body {
 background:#f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="triangle" style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/id/155/1000/800)"></div>
</div>

<div class="box adjust">
  <div class="triangle bottom" style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/id/159/1000/800)"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Although I scrapped the idea, I'm marking this as best answer as it seems to do exactly what I initially wanted